# Generic function that uses a delegate to centralize boilerplate code?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm writing a class that's similar to a WCF interface proxy but that has some specialized but boilerplate extra code in it. I would like to extract the boilerplate code and use a generic or other mechanism to wrap calls to an internal instance of a class.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  long fn1(int param1, int param2);
}

public class MyInterfaceProxy : IMyInterface
{
  // generated code
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
  private MyInterfaceProxy _myProxy; // implements IMyInterface
  public long fn1(int param1, int param2)
  {
    long result = null;
    CallMethod(
               delegate(IMyInterface svc)
               {
                   result = svc.fn1(param1, param2);
               });
    return result;
  }

  private T CallMethod( ??? )
     where T : class
  {
    T result = null;

    // some boilerplate code
    // Call the delegate, passing _myProxy as the IMyInterface to act on
    // some more boilerplate code

    return result;
  }
```

}

If it helps, the boilerplate code can represent retry logic, timeout behavior, standardized exception handling behavior, etc.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a standard or preferred way to solve this problem?
2. If generics are the preferred mechanism, what is the signature of the CallMethod function?

Comment: Can you use a base class and have CallMethod be a `protected` method in the base class?

Comment: Scratch my previous comment, that doesn't seem to be what you're asking for. I'm not sure I follow what you're asking, but as far as the call signature, can you make use of Func<T,T>?  Seems like that is the signature of CallMethod.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) for more on Func<T,TResult>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  There is a lot more that can be done composing functions.  This is the very surface scratching of functional programming paradigms, and it's really great that we can use some of it in c# now.

EDIT: added the anonymous function implementation as well to better simulate your delegate scenario.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string resFromFunctionToBeWRapped = CallMethod(() => FunctionToBeWrapped());

        int resFromAnon = CallMethod(() => {
            Console.WriteLine("in anonymous function");
            return 5;
        } );

        Console.WriteLine("value is {0}", resFromFunctionToBeWRapped);
        Console.WriteLine("value from anon is {0}", resFromAnon);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static TResult CallMethod<TResult>(Func<TResult> functionToCall) //where T : class
      {
        Console.WriteLine ("in wrapper");

        var ret = functionToCall();

        Console.WriteLine("leaving wrapper");

        return ret;
      }

    private static string FunctionToBeWrapped()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in func");
        return "done";
    }

}
```

Comment: This is VERY close to what I've come up with - to the point that I'm happy giving you the credit for the answer! The only adjustment was changing the Func from Func<TResult> to Func<TResult, KInterface> (since FunctionToBeWrapped takes a single parameter.)

protected K CallMethod<K>(Func<T, K> serviceInvoker)
            where K : class
        {
            K result = null;

            ServiceChannel.UseServiceClient(HostName, EndpointName, delegate(T svc)
            { result = serviceInvoker.Invoke(svc); });
            return result;
        }

Comment: Also, calling code I got working looks like "return CallMethod(svc => svc.fn1(1, 2));"